# CSV Import with GUID failing

Tags: asp.net, filehelpers

Looking for some quick help.

I am importing a CSV file that has 2 columns ID & Name. ID is a GUID and name is a String, as below:

```
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd06,Location99
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd07,Location100
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd08,Location101
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd09,Location102
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd10,Location103
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd11,Location104
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd12,Location105
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd13,Location106
c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd14,Location107
```

I have the following helper class defined:

```
<DelimitedRecord(",")>
    Public Class AssetLocationUpl
        <FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Guid, "D")>
        Public SiteID As Guid
        <FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)>
        Public LocationName As String
    End Class
```

But when I import the file i get the following error:

*FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting 'c4f8da96-b991-457e-9fd5-94e532ffcd100' to type: 'Guid'.*

Can someone point out what I have done wrong or how to get the import to work please :-)

Cheers,

Ozzie

Comment: It is supposed to be 36 chars. It seems you are incrementing the Guid. This works until 99, then it's 37 chars.

Comment: @VDWWD 100% right, I had generated some test data in Excel and it had incremented the GUID and I simply did not see it.

Answer (score 1):

I had generated some test data in Excel and it had incremented the GUID and I simply did not see it.